# How to create log file (path sohuld be ADLS) in databricks pyspark

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I have written a pyspark job in databricks. My objective is to save information, exception and errors into log file. This log file should be present in ADLS.

Can someone provide me guidance on this.

Comment: thats true . Is there any way to log output information in a log file

Comment: Could you solve it? I'm trying with `sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can [set logs](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/clusters/log-delivery.html) to be sent to a DBFS location by specifying it in the advanced settings of the cluster details page.

In the cluster page, click Edit and expand the Advanced Options. There's a Logging tab where you can input where you want the logs to go. Databricks will create a folder in this location based off the cluster ID.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i am not looking for cluster info logging. I want to log specifically output of my databricks job into a file for daily monitoring purpose

Comment: Oh, sorry for the misunderstanding. For that, perhaps you can utilize the REST API for Jobs? https://docs.databricks.com/api/latest/jobs.html#runs-export